# Residues of $f(z)=\frac{z^2-2z}{(z+1)^2(z^2+4)}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Find the residues of the following function

$$f(z)=\frac{z^2-2z}{(z+1)^2(z^2+4)}$$

What i tried

First i find the singularities which are $z=-1$, $z=2i$ and $z=-2i$.

Next i can see that $(z+1)^2$ is a pole of order $2$ and so using the standard formula to find residues i am able to solve it. What i am confused is the $(z^2+4)$ part, because my answer key says that its a pole of order $2$ but i thought its a pole of order $1$. How is it possible that its a pole of order $2$ Could anyone please explain. Thanks

Comment: You are making a category mistake: $(z+1)^2$ is not a "pole of order $2$", rather $f$ has a pole of order $2$ at $-1$. Also $f$ has poles of order $1$ at $2i$ and at $-2i$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to find first of all, the singularities as you said :

$$(z+1)^2 = 0 \Rightarrow z = -1$$

That means that your function $f$ has a pole of order $2$ as $z=-1$, **not that $(z+1)^2$ is a pole of order $2$** (this is a wrong expression).

$$z^2 + 4 = 0 \Rightarrow z = \pm 2i$$

That means that your function $f$ has poles of order $1$ at $z=2i$, $z=-2i$. ($2i \neq -2i$ obviously, so it **cannot** be a pole of order 2)

Comment: So i have to find the residues for the case of $z=2i$ and $z=-2i$ seperately and then add the answer to get the residues?

Comment: @yswong If your exercise is asking you to find the residues of the given function (recall that the residue is the constant $a_{-1}$, which means the coefficient of $z^{-1}$ in the Laurent Series of a function about a point $z_0$), then yes.

Comment: Is $a_{-2}$ considered a residue.

Comment: @yswong What? Please reread the **definition**.

Comment: Why the downvote ?

Comment: Im not the one who downvoted it.